# Draft approved, but does not show in main page?

Tags: support, documentation

My draft adding two examples was approved: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/15382?draftId=14761

However, the two examples don't show up in the live documentation page: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1379/parsing-command-line-arguments#t=2016072119194151538

Is this a bug, perhaps? My speculation is that there were two drafts were from "no topic page" to "topic page with some examples", one of the drafts was approved, and when mine was approved after, the page didn't update with the new examples.

Comment: You are using the wrong link http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1382/parsing-command-line-arguments/4501/docopt-basics#t=201607211923058166678 (btw, the UX is confusing)

Comment: There was a feature that every link is everlasting and that there would be a message on the top indicating that it wasn't the last revision... I wonder where that is...

Comment: Ahh, interesting. And I'm guessing it takes some time for the link to update from the all topics page.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, [I was wrong.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328701/draft-approved-but-does-not-show-in-main-page#comment370006_328701) What is likely the problem is that both you zundo handled the topic request at the same time. Both were approved and for each one a new topic was created. That's why https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1379/parsing-command-line-arguments and https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1382/parsing-command-line-arguments exist (same topic different id's) which provoked the current situation. I created a [move example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/19494) request to merge the examples of both topics.