# Approving two proposed changes to a requested topic creates duplicate topics

Tags: bug, documentation

I went to the requested topic section, saw that python Exceptions had some pending reviews and took a look.

One of the edits had a large set of great examples so I accepted it, creating a [Python Exceptions topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1712/exceptions).

Looking through the other suggestions for the topic, I saw that a different change had an entirely separate example that also fit the topic, so I accepted that one too. I expected this to merge the new example into the already created topic, but instead it created [another Python Exceptions topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1714/exceptions).

This behavior seems a bit off, can this type of scenario result in an automagic text merge (or at least a "hey don't do that" error) instead? Also how can I flag the duplicate topics to be merged?

Comment: Related [Draft approved, but does not show in main page?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328701)