# Can't move examples to an existing topic if there's a pending move waiting for the same topic (or so I think?)

Tags: bug, documentation, move-examples

I am trying to [solve this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328777/792066), but meanwhile I decided to move all examples to a single topic. That seems to be easy pie, just click move and voila! Well, the first one went [without a hitch](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/23777), [the second not so](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/python/1788/exceptions#t=201607220150584637064). Now I'm unable to either, submit the proposal, nor see any of the topics (target and sources) involved in the thing. Through I can access the [draft itself,](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/23777) the topics are unavailable.