# Can't open any draft, always return 500 error

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-topics, draft

If I try to edit/improve anything, the console gets filled up with 500. From there on, I can't either submit the draft or discard it, nor I can navigate back to the topic as I get an "Oops! Something Bad Happened!". Basically, each time that I open a draft for a topic, doesn't matter if it's mine or someones, I lock myself out of that topic for the time being. BTW, when submitting the draft a empty error box appears.

It may or may not have something to do with this [Can't move examples to an existing topic if there's a pending move waiting for the same topic (or so I think?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328823/792066), and I can't delete my drafts.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache and cookies? (And tried in another browser)

Comment: @TylerH private session and another browser, same thing happens.

Comment: Happens to me as well, so potentially related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328779/i-might-have-messed-up-docker Looks like the plague is spreading to you as well

Comment: Same problem here,. Occasionally the empty error box contains the text "Something bad happened"

Comment: I have the same problem.  Any time, I make try to make an edit to a topic, I can no longer access the topic.  So frustrating!

Comment: @null I think it was fixed.

Comment: Yes, I was able to delete lingering drafts and am able to access and interact with documentation without problems now.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed sometimes yesterday