# Can't open documentation topic, after move examples request

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-topics

When I open any topic and use function "move examples"

[image]

This error is showing:

[image]

And I can't open that topic any more:

[image]

Is there something I could do, to open those topics?

Comment: Probably related [Can't open any draft, always return 500 error](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328975)

Answer (score 1):

I deleted all my drafts from those topics, and now it works like a charm