# Moving examples to another tag fails (?) with error

Tags: bug, documentation

I found [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/documentation/1469/examples/17233/how-can-i-move-an-example-to-another-tag#t=201608031633068082922) on how to move examples to another tag, but when I tried, I got a strange error:

[image: "An error has occurred" is the best possible error message.]

When I clicked on the Reload link, I got redirected to https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/javascript/503/document-object-model-dom#t=201608031631493624383

And now I get a similar error whenever I try to go to the topic directly, similar to that reported [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330192/215552) or [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329030/cant-open-documentation-topic-after-move-examples-request?rq=1). It may be that I'm the only one who's getting the error, however.

I was using Chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 m (64-bit) on Windows 8.1 when the error occurred.

The full repro steps:

1. Clicked on the Move Examples button on the [Document Object Model (DOM) topic in the JavaScript tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/503/document-object-model-dom).
2. Checked all of the examples
3. Checked that I understood it would delete the topic
4. Clicked the Next button
5. Clicked Search for topic selection
6. Pasted the URL to the Intro to DOM topic on the DOM tag: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/dom/2584/introduction-to-dom
7. Clicked the Next button (or something, I forget the exact words)
8. Error occurs
9. ...
10. No profit :(

Comment: Testing this... Seems to be working so far, but I have to fix a fair number of versions since apparently someone thought classList and querySelector were part of ES6. Will update if I can actually submit the drafts.

Comment: This bug still exists. It occurred when I was trying to move an example to another tag. Now both those examples throw a 500 error.

http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/django/5392/use-pdb-for-real-time-debugging

http://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/django/5072/debugging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what caused the error you encountered; I went through the steps you outline with two different accounts and was unable to reproduce.

That said, there was definitely some weirdness added to the process by versions; we may have to do something here, since moving examples between tags is likely to be afflicted by this when the versions don't align:

[image: Version is not valid in this context]

The problem here is two-fold: the ES versions don't exist in the DOM topic, and it's not possible to *add* them (or otherwise adjust versions such that they validate) in the same draft that moves the examples. The only way around this is to strip the version information entirely, and then re-add it.

Since you ended up with [one draft that removes the examples from the source and deletes the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/drafts/62810), I'm guessing that something caused the creation of the second draft to fail.

Additional weirdness:

- Looking at [your draft](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/drafts/62810), you'll see two examples that *did not* appear in the topic when I was testing this ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/revisions/503?exampleId=1658), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/revisions/503?exampleId=15783)) as they'd been previously deleted...
- Trying to view the revision history for [the now-deleted topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/revisions/503) crashes.

Comment: Weird wild wacky stuff. Thanks for digging!