# A bug in "AngularJS" section in Documentation

Tags: bug, documentation

I have edited the [Custom directives](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/angularjs/965/custom-directives) topic by changing the `Parameters` aria with new content and submitted it to review.

Next, I have responded to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/documentation/improvement-requests/view/2615) improvement request, and updated the example with more details, But I also **Moved** it to the **Custom directives** while my last change is still [pending review](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/57446). I tried to submit my draft, but I got an error telling me that something went wrong and a **reload** link.

I tried to reload the page, but now nothing is working - All I see is **Oops! Something Bad Happened!** and a random picture of a guy "working on his problemz":

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/2615
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/965/custom-directives#t=201607262056578011959
- [81fad344-2c3c-45a2-8914-ce33731b7c93](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/965/custom-directives)

I get error in all the above links. Is it just for me?

Edit:

I still getting the error in the suggested link in the answer. Attached screenshot
[image]

Reproductions steps:

1. Edit the "parameters" section of an existing topic, and submit the changes for review
2. Respond to improvement request of example in a different topic with only that example in it
3. Edit the example
4. Move the example to the same topic in step 1 so the current topic will be deleted because it has no other examples, and submit for review (While the previous proposed change is still pending)

**Expected result**: 2 proposed changes will be submitted on the same topic, one for changing the "parameters" section, and the second change will edit the example and move it to its destination section (which is the same topic as in the first change) AND delete the source section of the example.

**Actual result**: An error occurs, and you're unable to load the change you tried to submit, and you get the same error when you try to see the any of the sections in the reproduction steps.

**Update**: Just wanted to let you know that now, when my [first change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/57446) is approved, I no longer get error when trying to access my [second draft](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/2615/creating-a-reusable-component-using-directives?draftId=48738) (I got error when the first change was pending)

Comment: Two bugs, maybe same cause [Can't move examples to an existing topic if there's a pending move waiting for the same topic (or so I think?)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328823) [Can't open any draft, always return 500 error](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328975)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, although i ran into it differently http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329675/cant-view-topic

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo I hope my reproduction steps will help to solve this

Answer (score 1):

All of those links are links to the error page, so... You'd expect to see an error page ;-)

Try these - they work for me:

- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/improvement-requests/view/2615
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/965/custom-directives#t=201607262056578011959
- [50efd771-86e4-4791-a11c-86a52c320936](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angularjs/965/custom-directives#t=201607262135402079509)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried them all and I see the same error (Attached a screenshot in the question)

Comment: Ok. Well, something is definitely broken then. But at least now we have a picture of Craver to confirm it.

Comment: I added reproduction steps so you can try on the testing env. I hope it will help you reproduce the bug on your side too

Comment: Update: Just wanted to let you know that now, when my [first change](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/57446) is approved, I no longer get error when trying to access my [second draft](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/57446) (I got error when the first change was pending) - But I'm not sure if I should submit it to review or discard it and try again

Comment: Submit it if it's still relevant, @Alon. If that breaks too, let me know.

Comment: Someone else already [deleted the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/58911) so I'll leave it as it is. I guess the bug happened when I moved example to a topic that I already edited (and before my edit was reviewed). It somehow allowed to system to create 2 drafts of the same topic