# Wait...what am I meant to be reviewing here?

Tags: bug, documentation, review-queues

(Hopefully for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/88246)

It's unclear to me from this screenshot what I'm meant to review:

[image]

...although I *guess* this is what it is?

[image]

If I click on the link present (moved to "File and I/O operations"), the link takes me right back to where I started.

The flow shouldn't feel so weird; it should be apparent where this particular topic was deleted *from* and where it's getting moved *to*.  I would like the focus to explicitly be on what it is I need to review here and I feel like the "moved 1 example out/moved 1 example in" bit is a bit confusing.

Comment: You should [feature-request] a better UI (one that doesn’t show all of that green ever).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The confusing part of this is that the Ruby documentation currently has two topics with the exact same name:

- [File and I/O operations](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/4035/file-and-i-o-operations)
- [File and I/O operations](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ruby/4310/file-and-i-o-operations)

The edit is attempting to combine the two topics together, by moving the example out of one into the other and deleting the now-empty topic.

This is a [known problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328777/approving-two-proposed-changes-to-a-requested-topic-creates-duplicate-topics) and hopefully coming up with a solution to prevent exact-duplicate titles like this will prevent confusing reviews like this appearing in the future.

Comment: Oh, okay.  That makes some sense.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Is there no way to add a change description?  If there is, the lack of such a description would tempt me to say "no" out of principle.

Comment: @Yakk I'm not sure. I know originally merging topics did not allow a change description as a normal edit would allow. I honestly don't know if that was changed or not.