# Who can delete a documentation example?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-topics

With documentation running wild, I joined the fun and added an example. I later checked back and noticed that someone had [deleted it](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/revisions/1379). Since the user is neither a moderator, nor a gold-tag-badge possessor, I was a little surprised that he could delete the topic single-handedly.

Who has the powers to delete a topic?

Comment: It wasn't deleted. It is moved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1382/parsing-command-line-arguments/4496/hello-world-in-argparse#t=201607220059530083932)

Comment: @sokin: Well, that is a little bit encouraging, but the `deleted it` link does indeed show `Braiam deleted this topic`.

Comment: Related [Draft approved, but does not show in main page?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328701)

Comment: BTW, the move required 3 users approval, 1 from the destination and two from the source https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/19494

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, anyone can delete an example. These becomes available under two circumstance:

- Someone flags your example, then the flag is reviewed and the post edited or deleted. Like everything edition and deletion needs someone to vouch for them, in the case of deletion it needs the approval of two users.
- Someone initiates a move request. The move is treated as a single "improvement", and needs 3 approvals, 1 from the destination and two from the deletion.

tl;DR, as long as two users vouch for you, you can basically delete any topic.

Comment: You can also click Edit, then Delete button, if Delete button is missing.

Comment: @nhahtdh I can't verify that because another bug [Can't open any draft, always return 500 error](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328975)