# Documentation Example - Improve instead of delete?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-examples

I'm still attempting to get my head around the documentation examples and what should be a topic or an example. To further add to my confusion [one of the examples](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/194/variables#t=201608031536101075535) I contributed to has been deleted, undeleted and then finally, a few days later, deleted again.

I've been attempting to check in on it when it's edited to make sure the information is still accurate and provides something useful for a documentation user to see. As far as I can tell, the information in that example doesn't feature elsewhere in the [PHP Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/194/variables#t=201608031540100800528) but in my opinion there are some common 'gotchas' that catch out new users that we have now lost.

**Is there a way to determine the reason for an example being deleted or in some way recover it?** I think it's a shame that the example has winked out of existence just like that if there was something we could improve about it instead. According to [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328813/who-can-delete-a-documentation-example) two people are able to delete a topic so I assume this is what happened in this situation.

---

As an aside, this is not about reputation. My reputation, or lack thereof, demonstrates my practice of only contributing if I think I can provide a rounded, useful answer. I personally think there should be [less reputation for documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329506/documentation-shares-the-work-make-the-rewards-shared-not-multiplicative) but that's another issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found where you proposed the change: [Page 3](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/revisions/194?page=3), [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/15279). An easy way to find all this would be from [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2233391/henders?tab=documentation).

The example was originally reverted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/41981).

According to the edit summary, it was deleted because:

> ... Conversions do not belong under variables. They are documented under PHP types topic. Adding a cross-reference to that topic for detail.

I suggest looking at the examples there to see if you can add anything there.

Comment: That's a bit clearer, thanks. I didn't think to look in the profile documentation tab. So [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/232/php-types/3880/type-casting#t=201608031615137202762) is the correct example for type casting now?

Comment: @Henders Looks like it.