# Documentation Example modified by other user and now deleted

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-examples

I invested my time and contributed an example in [Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/18/operators#t=201610071649475259157) in C# tag and it is approved my other users. I also provided Demo for this example - *[Available Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tNLLsI)*

[image]

But [This User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6308481/rodolfo-fadino-junior) totally removed my explanation, code and demo and added his own explanation and code.

[image]

But now this example is deleted due to its low quality:

[image]

So my question is Why some users are not paying attention to the Quality of Proposed Changes in Documentation Examples?

**And if an example is of low quality and it has more than one improvements then Is it possible to revert its changes to previous improvement?? *(Instead of deleting whole example)*.**
This [Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330532/documentation-example-improve-instead-of-delete) also pointed to this issue.

Comment: because some users who are reviewing don't care.

Comment: I mean, the edit did seem to improve the formatting and wording of the example. however I cannot comment on the accuracy of it.

Comment: There should be some rules to review documentation proposed changes. Like while committing a topic proposal, a user must have 150 reputations and at least 1 positive score answer for any tag.

Comment: You can just revert it. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: The user must have 100 rep to review.

Comment: No.. Can you please explain it?

Comment: Your version and the edited version both seem to say pretty much the same thing; the only substantive difference I see is that you say "`&` is bitwise, `&&` is logical," which is a pretty terrible explanation. Most people who don't know the difference between `&` and `&&` won't even know what the words "bitwise" and "logical" mean in this context.

Comment: Not to mention that "bitwise" and "logical" are not code and should not be marked as such.

Comment: Both versions of that example were removed for being low quality. Examples should contain prose that explains the subject matter as well as clear code demonstrating the explanation. Moreover, grouping `&` with `&&` is just going to lead to confusion as they have as much to do with each other as Java and JavaScript.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot if you see, after pointing out their `operations types`, I elaborated their working as well. And I also provided [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tNLLsI) for more clarifications.

Comment: ***To whom it may concern.!! Down voters!*** You have legal right to down vote this Question, But if there is any problem with this Question, please improve it by editing it or if it is not clear to you, tell me I'll make it clear to you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To revert this change, first click the revision history at the bottom of the page:

[image: edited XX ago]

Then, find your edit and click “View Topic.”

Next, click on “Create draft rolling back to this version:”

[image: Create draft rolling back to this revision]

Click “Submit for Review.”